# Compiling drivers/staging

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, make, gnu-make

I need to compile all staging drivers. I am using `make allyesconfig` and I have also set `CONFIG_BROKEN=y` and `CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST=y` .

Right now, `make modules C=1 M=drivers/staging` prints `MODPOST drivers/staging/Module.symvers` only.

(Is that the right command?)

Can someone help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
make mrproper
make allmodconfig
make -j3 all
make C=1 M=drivers/staging
```

You need to interrupt `make all` with a `sigint` once it starts compiling `init`

Also, `make allmodconfig` enables all modules. A lot of drivers are built as modules whereas `make allyesconfig` will just enable all config options.

Also, I've used `make -j3 all` because I use a 4 core processor. You can do `make -j$(nproc) all`

I terminate the process with a `SIGINT` or a `Ctrl+C` once I started observing CC flags continuously.

Also, `make mrproper` instead of `make clean` because `make clean` only cleans object files and `make mrproper` cleans everything.

This worked for me, let me know if I am wrong. :)