# How to install non-FUSE Samsung's open-source exFAT driver?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, fuse, exfat

I've had problems with the FUSE driver `exfat-fuse`, in some particular cases (Samba share, etc.).

So I wanted to test the [new Samsung's exFAT driver (open-source)](https://www.linux.com/news/samsung-releases-exfat-utils-to-format-file-system-fsck/). I see it's merged in Linux kernel 5.7, but I only have kernel 5.4.

**Question: how is it possible to install this driver (as a module?) on a 5.4 Linux?**

Comment: Unless I understand it completely wrong, the work has already been done: https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux ...

Answer (score 2):

The driver has been in staging [since kernel 5.4](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/drivers/staging/exfat).

So you would need to [compile the kernel with drivers/staging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598311/compiling-drivers-staging) and include that module.

Then, if needed, you'd backport the changes from 5.7 to 5.4.

You could also go the other way around, trying to backport the kernel 5.7 driver to kernel 5.4.